# Python Mysql variable with %

Tags: python, mysql

```
def getstuff(letter):
 curSelect.execute("SELECT id,name,age FROM `people` where name like %s ",(letter) )

 getstuff('A')
```

My problem is that i am trying to get a list of everyone in the database that starts with A
So how can i get

```
getstuff('A%')
```

To be passed?

I keep getting

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Try using `""" """"` parantheses instead of `' '`

Comment: I think `%s` should be enclosed in single quotes: `'%s'`

Comment: Nu luck iam afraid, thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the comma (,) in the params tuple:

```
curSelect.execute(\
       "SELECT id, name, age FROM people where name like %s",\
       (letter,)\
)
```

and then:

```
getstuff('A%')
```

Comment: Now i feel rather stupid:) Thanks alot! It solved my problem.